# removing all the characters except numbers

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Could you please help me rewrite the following CP so when it reads from the file to remove any other characters except numbers: 
    what it does is read a file for example block.txt and addes each line into the table.

```
USE [db_Test]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[Cp_ImportBlackList]
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION Acbc

DECLARE @command nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @delcommand varchar(200)

DECLARE @txtfile nvarchar(200)

DECLARE @line nvarchar(2)

DECLARE @andreas nvarchar(200)

set @line='\n'

DECLARE @isExists INT

 DECLARE @tempcol int

 DECLARE MyCursor cursor fast_forward for
    Select Users_ID from Prj_Users


open MyCursor

fetch next from MyCursor

into @tempcol

while @@fetch_status = 0

begin

set @txtfile = 'c:\BlackList\ ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(str(@tempcol))) + '.txt'
exec master.dbo.xp_fileexist @txtfile,
@isExists OUTPUT
if (@isExists =1)

begin

BEGIN TRY

BEGIN TRANSACTION ad

set @command=' BULK INSERT Prj_TempBlackList   FROM  ''' + @txtfile + ''''

set @command += '  WITH( ROWTERMINATOR  = '''+ @line +''' )'

print @command

    EXECUTE(@command)

  delete Prj_TempBlackList where Tell in(select [BLList_TEll] from prj_BlackList where [BLList_UserID]  =  @tempcol)
  insert into prj_BlackList select DISTINCT Tell,@tempcol from Prj_TempBlackList where Tell not in(select [BLList_TEll] from prj_BlackList where [BLList_UserID] =  @tempcol)
      delete from Prj_TempBlackList
 set @delcommand ='del ' +  @txtfile
 exec xp_cmdshell @delcommand

 print 'end'

  COMMIT TRANSACTION ad

  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH

 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ad

 SELECT ERROR_Message() AS ErrorNumber;

END CATCH

end

else

print 'no'

fetch next from MyCursor

into @tempcol

end

close MyCursor

deallocate MyCursor

set @txtfile = 'c:\BlackList\block.txt'

exec master.dbo.xp_fileexist @txtfile,

@isExists OUTPUT

if (@isExists =1)

begin

BEGIN TRY

BEGIN TRANSACTION ada

set @command=' BULK INSERT Prj_TempBlackList   FROM  ''' + @txtfile + ''''

set @command += '  WITH( ROWTERMINATOR  = '''+@line+''' )'

    EXECUTE(@command)

delete Prj_TempBlackList where Tell  in(

  select [BLList_TEll] from prj_BlackList where [BLList_UserID] is null)
  insert into prj_BlackList SELECT DISTINCT Tell,null from 
Prj_TempBlackList where Tell not in(
  select [BLList_TEll] from prj_BlackList where [BLList_UserID] is null)
  delete from Prj_TempBlackList
 set @delcommand ='del ' +  @txtfile
 exec xp_cmdshell @delcommand

 print 'yes'

  COMMIT TRANSACTION ada

  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH

 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ada

 SELECT ERROR_Message() AS ErrorNumber;

END CATCH

end



    COMMIT TRANSACTION Acbc

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION Acbc

END CATCH

END
```

Comment: If the data is in a file, why are you using SQL Server for this purpose?  There are many better tools for processing files.

Comment: Is it necessary to do your entire ETL process within a stored procedure? It is not an efficient way of doing. You would be much better off using something like SSIS, where you load your file, then you a script component transformation, to leverage .NET's regex functions ([similar to this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/531971/SSIS-Transform-data-using-Regex)), then load into your destination table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid CURSORs and LOOPs!

This approach does it *on the fly*, but you really should think about if TSQL is the right tool...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, EvilString NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl(EvilString) VALUES('ab23cd56jkl'),(' adfhasd l h45 hagf 78 l 9');

WITH RunningNumbers AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A) AS Nmbr
    FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tblA(A)
        ,(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tblB(B)
        ,(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tblC(C)
        ,(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tblD(D)
        ,(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tblE(E)
        ,(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tblF(F)
)
,SingleChars AS
(
    SELECT tbl.ID,rn.Nmbr,SUBSTRING(tbl.EvilString,rn.Nmbr,1) AS Chr
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(LEN(tbl.EvilString)) Nmbr FROM RunningNumbers) AS rn 
)
SELECT ID,EvilString
      ,(
        SELECT '' + Chr 
        FROM SingleChars AS sc
        WHERE sc.ID=tbl.ID AND ASCII(Chr) BETWEEN 48 AND 57
        ORDER BY sc.Nmbr
        FOR XML PATH('')
      ) AS GoodString
FROM @tbl As tbl
```

The result

```
ID  EvilString                  GoodString
1   ab23cd56jkl                 2356
2    adfhasd l h45 hagf 78 l 9  45789
```